# Problems initializing an array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an array that is obtained from a query to the database by api when inserting it into the array it shows me the normal data but when passing it to the useState it returns me undefined

**- Declare User**

```
const [ userEdit, setUserEdit ] = useState<User>();
```

**- The useEffect is used to bring the data from the api in a json format**

```
useEffect(() => {
        editUser(query.id).then((response) => setUserEdit(response['0']));
    }, []);
```

**- Const**

```
const inititalState = {
        'id' : query.id,
        'name' : userEdit?.name,
        'lastname' : userEdit?.lastname,
        'email' : userEdit?.email,
        'username' : userEdit?.username,
        'password' : userEdit?.password,
        'phar_id' : userEdit?.phar_id,
        'rol_id' : userEdit?.rol_id,
        'sub_id' : userEdit?.sub_id,
    };
```

**- Result in colsole**

```
email: "prueba@gmail.com"
id: "11"
lastname: "Apellido"
name: "nombre"
password: "$2y$10$XyGh/xzbZXDky06kuFBRa.dNXcqwr7cIJbYUjPhDUfsCi4LNGpVEe"
phar_id: 1
role_id: 2
sub_id: 1
username: "usuario001"
```

**- At the time of sending it to the state**

```
const [ updateUser, setUser ] = useState(inititalState);
```

**- Result in console**

```
email: undefined
id: "11"
lastname: undefined
name: undefined
password: undefined
phar_id: undefined
rol_id: undefined
sub_id: undefined
username: undefined
```

Comment: If `initialState` is a result of a query, the `updateUser state` is initialized before the query is done. You need when the query is finished to `setUser(queryResult)`

Comment: When do you call setUser? Try to share the whole code if possible

Comment: one moment, please

Comment: Rready can you help me @Ingenious_Hans

Comment: ```useState``` updates using the ```set...``` calls are asynchronous. If you post the entire codebase, that should help to solve your issue faster.

Comment: Can you share the whole code please, at least all the logic

Comment: "Result in console" - What & where is this log in your code example? Can you edit the post to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can either implement async/await approach or otherwise create another state variable such as:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)


const fetchData = () => {
      editUser(query.id).then((response) => setUserEdit(response['0'])).finally(() => setLoading(false))
}
```

Now you can choose to call fetchData() anywhere in your code and post function invocation, to view the data try something like

```
!loading && console.log("name:", userEdit?.name)
```

Hope this helps! Any further clarity needed you can feel free to follow up in the comments.